# Which layout and control is suitable for sliding window where icons will be appearing in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I am developing an application where i need icons to be floating on my panel. I am not sure which control and layout will be suitable for this. I am attaching an image to make you understand what i mean. I want the same two column icon based layout. And if i will scroll down it should be in a sliding way and scroll down. Please let me know which layout and control is suitable for sliding window where icons will be appearing in Android. I am new bie so i am sorry if its not a good question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of items, you could simply use `LinearLayout`s (with a `ScrollView` as the root view of the layout). If you have a large number of items or you don't know in advance how many items you will have, use a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) (and do not place it inside of a `ScrollView`).